# Non-empty array returns undefined when selecting its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've coded this class that upon being instantiated retrieves data from the database and for each record found instatiates an `Issue` object which is immediately stored into an array.

```
import { Issue } from "./Issue.js";

class App {

    constructor() {
        
        this.issues = [];

        fetch("/issues")
           
            .then(response => {

                if(response.ok) return response.json();
            })
            
            .then(issues => {

                issues.forEach(model => {
                    
                    let issue = new Issue(model);
                    this.issues.push(issue);
                })
            });

        console.log(this.issues);
    }
}
    
let app = new App();
```

This code prints out an array containing as many objects as there are records in the database.

[image]

However, what's weird is that if I try to print an element of this array as this:

```
console.log(this.issues[0]);
```

The output that I get is just "undefined". What's happening here?

Comment: The array is empty when you log it. Move the log inside the `then` callback.

Comment: And in general, [don't start asynchronous tasks inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).